# Determine this real integral with the Residue-theorem.

Tags: trigonometry, residue-calculus, complex-integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin x}{x^4-6x^2+10}\,\mathrm dx}$$

I get that when I evaluate the $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ one, I work with $\frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2ix}$, I create a huge semicircle and a small one from $-\varepsilon$ to $\varepsilon$. Should I do the same here? And evaluate the integral of the small semicircle with $z=\varepsilon\cdot e^{i\varphi}$? And if the bigger semicircle gives zero, my integral equals to minus the small semicircle.
Will I need the residues at all? Or is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: It could just be that it's late and I'm missing something, but isn't the integrand odd $\implies I = 0$?

Comment: Yes, but $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not an odd function, whilst $\frac{\sin x}{x^4 - 6x^2+10}$ is.

Comment: The given integral is indeed zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Since $x^4-6x^2+10$ has no real zeros try to replace $\sin x$ with $\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}$ via the Euler formula and take only the imaginary part of it like
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^4-6x^2+10}\,\mathrm dx = \operatorname{Im}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}}{x^4-6x^2+10}\,\mathrm dx\right)$$
since you will get a Fourier integral of the form $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}\mathrm e^{\mathrm iz}\,\mathrm dz=2\pi\mathrm i\sum_{z\in Q^{-1}(\{0\}),\operatorname{Im}z>0}\operatorname{Res}_{w=z}\left(\frac{P(w)}{Q(w)}\mathrm e^{\mathrm iw}\right).$$
However the given integral has value zero which can be shown in multiple ways.

Comment: Just a small question - do I need the small semicircle in every integral which has sinx?

Comment: @NicoleJudge Which one are you actually referring to? The arc $\gamma(t)=R\mathrm e^{\mathrm it},t\in[0,\pi]$ with $R\to\infty$? If you ask when to replace $\sin x$ with $\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}$ with respect to the imaginary part then the answer is: pretty often since $\sin$ is quite nasty but $\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}$ can be helpful to deduce a Fourier integral as mentioned.